# UILabel dynamic height with UIImageView Constant height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel

In UITableViewCell i am having one imageview and two label with dynamic height and a button, i used autolayout constraints to achieve dynamic row height and expanding UILabel height, i followed [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) tutorial, now i want to fix the imageview height to be constant, but if i do this by giving height constraint then the dynamic height for the UILabel is getting affected and it is truncating to one line, to do this i think i want to use some more constraints, kindly help me.

I tried by changing the content hugging priority and content compression resistance priority but i am unable to do it. I tried giving aspect ratio for image, that also affecting the uilabel dynamic height.

This is my UITableViewCell with the constraints i gave

[image: This is my UITableViewCell with the constraints i gave]

[image: Like this the imageview is getting stretched]

Like this the imageview is getting stretched

Comment: Remove bottom constraint from imageview and set fixed height to it

Comment: Thank you @Baig it helped me to acheive what i want exactly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `ThumbImage` with this code and don't set constraint for `ThumbImage`'s height.

```
thumbImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Welcome @R.Mohan :)